# Inserting white space into an array

Tags: java, arrays

Say I have an array of random numbers such as:

```
int [] x = {3,45,17,2,-1,44,9,23,67,2,-6,-23,-100,12,5,1212};
```

How do I insert white space between each integer?

Comment: You mean you want to print it out with space in between?

Comment: press space bar?

Comment: @user902383. The most under-estimating answer/comment I have ever seen. ;)

Comment: change it to String array, then add spaces. int array will not accept spaces.

Comment: Let your IDE format your code.

Comment: @Idan Ya.. that would be fine... he would just need to do a Integer.parseInt(String.split("")[i]); on a loop and his appetite for entering space will also be fulfilled.

Answer (score 2):

You can't if they are a type integer - the spaces are not stored.

You will need to create an array of Strings if you want to store spaces.

If you just want to print them out with a space use...

```
private final static int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i : numbers) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have object array with space but not int array

```
     int [] x = {3,45,17,2,-1,44,9,23,67,2,-6,-23,-100,12,5,1212};
    Object [] o = new Object[x.length];

    for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        o[i] = x[i]+" ";
        System.out.println(o[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Why `Object` and not `String`? In fact, why do this at all? I don't think this is what the OP was asking for, although admittedly this hasn't been made clear yet.